Event: when theme swapped
I want to do some clean-up when my theme is changed out: unregistering cron jobs and other theme-specific things.
I've been trying to look for an event that fires when my theme is being swapped out (but is still in scope) - I haven't been able to find any.
There's after_switch_theme, but that fires when a new theme is active.
Is there an appropriate event for this? Or how should we ideally handle cleaning up after our themes are no longer active?

theme are supposed to manage the display of public pages and not to touch to data, are you sure you need to put these cron jobs in the theme ? to act when the theme is going to be changed, look this action : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/switch_theme/

@mmm Oh yeah, switch_theme works! Since the documentation said it fire after I assumed it wouldn't work, like after_switch_theme. Cheers!
